# Folder's content are empty after pushing into bitbucket

Tags: gitlab, bitbucket

I wanted to push folders from my local repositories into bit bucket. Somehow I was unable to do that.

I got the solution somewhere to use

```
$ git push -f origin master
```

which resolved the issue but erased all lines of code. 
This is my very first use of bit bucket. How to get all content back?

Now, I deleted previous repository and created the new one. Typed below but getting error

```
$ git remote add origin 
https://PoojaThapa@bitbucket.org/PoojaThapa/git-poojatest.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.

$ git push origin
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
An error occurred while sending the request.
remote: Not Found
fatal: repository 'https://PoojaThapa@bitbucket.org/PoojaThapa/git- 
test.git/' not found
```

please suggest.

Comment: With git you push files and not folder

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a repository in your current directory you can add a remote with any name using:

```
git remote add <remote-name> <url>
```

You are getting an error with your first command because a remote already exists called `origin`.

Try `git remote -v` to see which remotes you have already got defined.

In your case I think you want to create a new remote (with a different name, for example `bitbucket`), so

```
git remote add bitbucket https://PoojaThapa@bitbucket.org/PoojaThapa/git-poojatest.git
```

Verify that the remote was created correctly using `git remote -v`, then you can push to the new remote using `<remote-name>/<branch>`:

```
git push bitbucket/master
```

Answer (score 0):

"repository not found" implies that the origin URL is incorrect. List your current remotes with `git remote -v`, and double-check that you have the correct URL(s) listed. (You should be able to go to the URL in your browser.)

If something is incorrect, you can fix it with `git remote set-url origin correct-url-goes-here`.